# sudo option works with terminal, but not with xwindow

Tags: linux, ubuntu

According to our office Admin rules, developer's machines should not have admin privilege, which i hated so much. so i decided to enable the sudo access with some work around found in web (booting with single user mode). and did it successfully but one strange behaviour which i don’t know why.

```
1) sudo option works in terminal (like if i install any application through terminal)

2) i cannot open synaptic package manager for which you need admin privilege with my user i am not able to open it.
```

so my question how my user is administrator while working with terminal but not with xwindow application (gnome or kde).

is console and gnome applications uses different sudoers file.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm stating the obvious here, but did you remember to actually use sudo when launching synaptic? (see [graphical sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo))

```
gksudo synaptic
```

Comment: actually i tried after saw your answer that is working, but still through terminal, if i open through gnome panel Application -> System -> synaptic package manager then it is not.

Comment: even normal sudo synaptic command will work (but not recommended). is console and gnome applications uses different sudoers file.?

Comment: That is because gnome-shell runs the command "synaptic", without sudo or gksudo prepended. You can create a custom launcher for the application as follows: `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop ~/.local/share/applications` (not sure if that's the correct name for the launcher, but it should be close), `sudo chown $USER ~/.local/share/applications/synaptic.desktop`, prepend gksudo to the command by editing the file (i.e `Exec=gksudo synaptic`) (see [how-to-create-a-custom-launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112186/how-do-you-create-a-custom-application-launcher-in-gnome-shell))

Comment: thanks for the answer it did work for this scenario (opening application), but if i open  user and group application and tried to alter the account privilege that time also it is asking for admin privilege, may be i am not asking the right question. but your answer is right and working.

Comment: Not sure if I understand completely, but it is normal to be asked for the a password when administering users. This is basically the same as running gksudo, you should be granted access with your ordinary user password (i.e. no need for the root password).